# Unable to create new junit test case in helios

Tags: eclipse, testing, junit, case, helios

I'm currently using the Eclipse Helios IDK and have the newest JRE (1.6) installed. I have added both the 4.8 and 4.9 versions of the junit jar to the build path. However, whenever I right click>new there is not an option to create a junit test case like you would expect. Even after going to other>java and every other directory within other I couldn't find the option to create a test case. Do I need to get a plugin in order to initialize these .jar files?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By default (and in my Helios, too) JUnit Test Case should be available even if no JUnit jar is in your classpath. Eclipse then asks to add the JUnit jar to the classpath.

Try removing the jars and start the "New.." wizard again.

[image]

Comment: That goes with everything I've seen and heard, and I can't find anyone even having the same issue as me. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hYgIB.png)

Comment: Even not under Other -> Java - JUnit? - This is really strange. Maybe you should unzip the Eclipse package again and check if it still isn't there.

Comment: I downloaded helios from a different source and replaced all the program files with the new ones. My project remained intact, but now junit shows up as a folder under the "other" option. Problem solved! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Vince: If your problem is solved and @timbooo's answer helped then please mark his answer as accepted. Thanks.